# Editing Pfile for Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am manually setting paramaters for a pfile for a database. I have been put to do this at work, and am not extremely knowledgable of how it works. That being said, the file is titled MSNinit.ora:

Some files start like this:

```
MSNlmv.__db_cache_size=889192448
MSNlmv.__java_pool_size=16777216
MSNlmv.__large_pool_size=16777216
```

others start with a "*" like this:

```
*.nls_length_semantics='CHAR'
*.open_cursors=2048
*.processes=500
```

I need to add the following parameters:

```
 db_block_checksum='TRUE
 db_files=500 
 dml_locks=10000 
 filesystemio_options='SETALL' 
 max_dump_file_size='52428800' 
 nls_length_semantics='CHAR' 
 open_cursors=2048 
 open_links=16 
 optimizer_dynamic_sampling=2 
 optimizer_mode='FIRST_ROWS_100'  
 plsql_optimize_level=1 
 processes=2000 
 session_cached_cursors=1024 
 sec_case_sensitive_logon=false 
 _unnest_subquery=FALSE 
 _B_TREE_BITMAP_PLANS FALSE 
_optimizer_join_elimination_enabled FALSE 
 deferred_segment_creation FALSE 
 nls_date_format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' 
 nls_timestamp_format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF'
 audit_trail db_extended 
 event "10298 trace name context forever, level 32
```

which ones use which notation? I dont know the syntax!

Thanks,
Anne

Comment: I suppose you have access to the Enterprise Manager; you can change those parameters there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ones that start with * are for all instances that connect to that database.
The ones that start with the Instance name are only for the instance with that name.
The ones that start with "InstanceName.__" are dynamic memory parameters that the database has set.

Unless you are running RAC all parameters that you edit/add in the file should begin with *.